# How to exclude third party extensions while upgrading magento 2.3.3 to 2.3.6?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, composer, mageplaza

I am upgrading Magento from 2.3.3 to 2.3.6 but one of my third-party extension is looking for an update from GitHub but that extension is not available in GitHub so I want to exclude that particular extension from an update.

For reference please please find the attached image.
[image]

Comment: You have to run composer remove [extension_name] then after you can upgrade M2 using composer. you can't exclude the third party extensio.

Comment: I had removed the extension even though I am getting same problem

Comment: Check your composer.json file and remove that extension or comment it out - then composer update

Comment: @somutesting, Install Extention via composer ???

Comment: They are now forcing you to pay for that extension to use composer to install it. So your choice is to pay for it or download the public files from github and either create an artifact for composer or install it in app/code.

Comment: @Himanshu yes installed from compoer

Comment: @Mark Rees there is no repository in the GitHub is there any way to get that original file expect paid version

Comment: composer remove mageplaza/module-image-optimizer

Comment: @somutesting the github is empty  if you still have the files in vendor you could pull them out and set them up into app/code otherwise you need to pay.

Comment: @Himanshu I had done the same process even though I am getting the same problem

Comment: Is there a Image Optimizer module in your project ??

Answer (score 0):

We had installed image optimiser from GitHub after few days later they removed the complete repository from GitHub sfter that we are trying to update Magento 2.3.3 to 2.3.6. Here we are facing the problem with image optimiser extension. We had removed extension from our application even though still it is looking for image optimiser extension update from GitHub.
So We have to remove that image optimiser extension from composer.json in root folder of the application